# Is my black-bordered foil from 8th edition a counterfeit? Where can I find more copies?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, legal

I have a black-bordered 8th edition foil [Thorn Elemental](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Thorn%20Elemental). I really like this card, and I tried to find a place where I can buy it again. However, I can only find white-bordered versions of this card in the 8th edition.

Does this mean I have a counterfeit card, or is there a black-bordered foil version in the 8th edition? I have not coloured in the border as other questions have suggested. I just can't seem to find a black border 8th edition foil, even on the main Magic wizards site.

I know that white-bordered cards can be played. I'm just a bit confused as to how my black-bordered card cannot be found anywhere.

Comment: I found a black border signed foil of the 8th edition: https://www.abugames.com/card236789-412441/Thorn-Elemental---FOIL---SIGNED---ID-s4299-Signed-Magic-Cards-Magic-The-Gathering-Single-Card.html

Comment: Is _your version_ an 8th edition card? It sounds like it might be, but we can't very well tell you if it's counterfeit if we don't know what your card is (other than black bordered).

Comment: Yes sorry if that wasn't made clear

Comment: That signature card is my exact card (obviously without the signature)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [MTG Salvation](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Foil_card):

> All foil cards are black-bordered, even those from the last white-bordered core sets, except those from Unhinged which are silver-bordered.

A black-bordered foil [Thorn Elemental](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Thorn%20Elemental) is valid anywhere any other Thorn Elemental is. You can find it, for example, [here](http://www.mtgotraders.com/store/8ED_Thorn_Elemental_f.html). Some sites just don't show separate images for foil versions of cards.

Comment: Ah it mentions gift coupons at that site do you have an idea where I can get them from?

Comment: No idea, it was just the first one I found with a picture of the listed foil.